# Why table in libgdx game give wrong position

Tags: java, android, game-design, libgdx

Can anybody guide me, I am creating a table in libgdx game on menu screen to set different buttons on my screen. here is the code for table draw

```
 table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

and here is the code for background for this menu screen

```
batch.draw(bckTexture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

My bcktexture image size is 600 by 400.

Now this table draws in the middle of the screen. I dont understand this why. it should be drawn by 0 , 0 corner and fill the whole screen. 
I have checked table by table.debug();

what I want is that the table should cover the whole screen so that I can adjust my buttons anywhere on the screen i want especially at the corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setBounds()` method comes from the `Actor` class, which the `Table` class subclasses. It is usually used for stuff like collision detection, but not setting the size of your actors.

In your case, you can go as simple as calling `table.setFillParent(true);` to have your table fill up the entire space in its parent (btw, are you adding it to a stage or something?)

Otherwise, use the `setSize()` and `setPosition()` methods to explicitly set size and position of your table inside its parent.

You might also want to check out this tutorial on using tables in libGDX: [TableLayout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout).

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually i was using stage as well but i was confused with setBounds as I thought it might give size to table. as Table always get draw in the center of the screen. but I used view port for stage and my problem solved.

Comment: setSize() and setPosition() does the exact same thing as setBounds() but separately

Answer (score 0):

Is your camera centered? If your camera is not centered, then it may be looking at (0, 0), which from your perspective is the center of the screen.